# responsive navigation links wont react to class

Tags: css

I am working on a website [simplemedia.dk](http://simplemedia.dk)

i have a responsive menu that works, but when i am trying to define the

in responsive mode the browsers does not recognize the style ..

in responsive mode i get a class called "responsified" and i tried adding the class .responsified in front of my navigation style but it doesnt react to it.

```
.responsive-menus .responsive-menus-0-0 .absolute .responsified .responsive-toggled #navigation ul.menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.responsive-menus .responsive-menus-0-0 .absolute .responsified .responsive-toggled #navigation ul.menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

In normal mode i want it to display table-cell which it does, but in responsive i want it to show block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a long space-separated string in your CSS selector like this...

```
.responsive-menus .responsive-menus-0-0 .absolute .responsified .responsive-toggled
```

...you are telling the browser "find me something with the class .responsive-toggled which has a parent with the class .responsified which in turn has a parent with the class .absolute which in turn has a parent with the class .responsive-menus-0-0...", etc. etc.

In your actual page, all those classes listed above are applied to a single element.

In CSS, to target an element with multiple classes, you chain them (no spaces):

```
.responsive-menus.responsive-menus-0-0.absolute.responsified.responsive-toggled
```

But this is almost certainly way, WAY more complicated than you need for this situation.

Your situation probably needs nothing more specific than this:

```
.responsified #navigation ul.menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.responsified #navigation ul.menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Certainly didn't mean to make you feel stupid, everyone's got to start learning how this stuff works somewhere!